# Можно ли искать операторы (===)?

Tags: предложение

Можно ли как-то сделать поиск по *операторам* языков, таких как =(присвоение) ==(сравнение) ===(строгое сравнение) и другим (+,- скобки |&*)? Пытался понять присутствует ли вопрос о строгом сравнении в базе so - но операторы поиск не ищет. Как пример вот: [В чем разница между == и ===?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431662/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B8)

Comment: в качестве обходного пути можно зайти на [data.stackexchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/539332)